# How to loop over json data and merge values in Python

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, merge

I have a json structure that looks like this. I would want to traverse the json and merge some of the values. I am new to python and trying to find a way to do this

Original Json that looks like this

```
{ 
      "Feedback": [

        {
            "Recipient_UserName": "John.Doe",
            "Feedback_Received_Anytime_group": [
                {
                    "Feedback_From": "Mr X",
                    "Feedback_Given": "Thanks for your work!",
                    "Feedback_Badge": "Own It",
                    "Feedback_From_UserName": "mr.x"
                }
            ],
            "Recipient": "John Doe",
            "Feedback_Date": "09/29"
        },
        {
            "Recipient_UserName": "Mickey.Mouse",
            "Feedback_Received_Anytime_group": [
                {
                    "Feedback_From": "Mr X",
                    "Feedback_Given": "Thanks for your work!",
                    "Feedback_Badge": "Own It",
                    "Feedback_From_UserName": "mr.x"
                }
            ],
            "Recipient": "Mickey Mouse",
            "Feedback_Date": "09/29"
        },{
            "Recipient_UserName": "Brad.Pitt",
            "Feedback_Received_Anytime_group": [
                {
                    "Feedback_From": "Donald Duck",
                    "Feedback_Given": "Massive achievement!!",
                    "Feedback_Badge": "Own It",
                    "Feedback_From_UserName": "donald.duck"
                }
            ],
            "Recipient": "Brad Pitt",
            "Feedback_Date": "09/22"
        }

        ]

}
```

I want it to look something like this below where I can merge same values  based on some keys.

```
{
   "Feedback":[
      {
         "Recipient_UserName":[
            "John.Doe",
            "Mickey.Mouse"
         ],
         "Feedback_Received_Anytime_group":[
            {
               "Feedback_From":"Mr X",
               "Feedback_Given":"Thanks for your work!",
               "Feedback_Badge":"Own It",
               "Feedback_From_UserName":"mr.x"
            }
         ],
         "Recipient":[
            "John Doe",
            "Mickey Mouse"
         ],
         "Feedback_Date":"09/29"
      },
      {
         "Recipient_UserName":"Brad.Pitt",
         "Feedback_Received_Anytime_group":[
            {
               "Feedback_From":"Donald Duck",
               "Feedback_Given":"Massive achievement!!",
               "Feedback_Badge":"Own It",
               "Feedback_From_UserName":"donald.duck"
            }
         ],
         "Recipient":"Brad Pitt",
         "Feedback_Date":"09/22"
      }
   ]
}
```

Any help/direction provided is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the condition when two entries should be merged? Have you tried anything yet? StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.